# PROC OLAP: ERROR: The requested action cannot be performed because user"" does not have WriteMemberMetadata permission to the folder

Tags: sas, metadata, olap, cube, olap-cube

I am trying to build OLAP cubes using PROC OLAP in SAS. I am new to this and am not able to understand how to resolve the following error:

```
ERROR: The requested action cannot be performed because user "usernmae" does not have WriteMemberMetadata permission to the folder.
```

Here is my code:

```
data a;
set sashelp.bweight;
count=1;
run;

proc olap cube='cube' data=a drillthrough_table=a path= "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Practice";
metasvr host="hostname" port=1234 userid="userid" pw="password" olap_schema="SASApp - OLAP Schema";
Dimension boy caption="boy" sort_order=ascending
hierarchies=(boy);
hierarchy boy all_member="all_segmentation" caption="segmentation"
levels=(married black) default ;
level married caption="married" sort_order=ascending;
level black caption="black" sort_order=ascending;
measure count stat=sum column=count caption="count of people";
run;
```

I believe I don't have write access to the repository where metadata for the cube is being stored and if that is the case, is it possible to store the metadata on my desktop itself? I am using SAS Enterprise Guide.

Answer (score 0):

The metadata for that OLAP cube is being stored on the SAS Metadata Server. It's a really large system that handles a whole lot of things, from permissions to column attributes to library locations.

You will need to contact one of your SAS administrators to give you the correct access to that OLAP cube. They will enable the `WriteMemberMetadata` permission for you, which can be seen here in this example from SAS Management Console:

[image: SMC Example]

Comment: Hi Stu, thanks for the help. I wanted to know if it is possible to store the metadata on a local folder on my system itself? Or else, if there is some way possible to make the cube without having those permissions from the administrator?

Comment: Because you are accessing the OLAP cube through the SAS Metadata Server, it is not possible to store the metadata on your system. The SAS Metadata Server is authenticating you to provide read/write permissions to the object. This is the primary way in which SAS 9.x controls user security for libraries & objects. It also maintains consistency of the metadata about these objects for multiple users. Allowing users to store metadata about an object on their own system would cause consistency issues, and both users and the server would not truly be able to know the attributes of the shared object.